# Generic list heapsort in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

This is an implementation of heapsort as seen on Programming Pearls, adapted for java List collections. It is working on a copy of the list passed-in on purpose at the moment.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public final class HeapSort {

    private HeapSort() {}

    public static <T extends Comparable<T>> List<T> heapSort(List<T> unsortedList) {
        assert unsortedList != null;
        assert unsortedList.size() > 1;
        List<T> sortedList = new ArrayList<T>(unsortedList);
        for (int i = 1; i < sortedList.size(); i++) {
            sortedList = siftUp(sortedList, i);
        }
        for (int i = sortedList.size() - 1; i >= 1; i--) {
            sortedList = swap(sortedList, 0, i);
            sortedList = siftDown(sortedList, i - 1);
        }
        return sortedList;
    }

    private static <T extends Comparable<T>> List<T> siftUp(List<T> unsortedList, int n) {
        assert n > 0;
        for (int i = n;;) {
            if (i == 0) {
                break;
            }
            int p = i / 2;
            if (unsortedList.get(p).compareTo(unsortedList.get(i)) >= 0) {
                break;
            }
            unsortedList = swap(unsortedList, i, p);
            i = p;
        }
        return unsortedList;
    }

    private static <T extends Comparable<T>> List<T> siftDown(List<T> unsortedList, int n) {
        for (int i = 0;;) {
            int c = 2 * (i + 1) - 1;

            if (c > n) {
                break;
            }
            if (c + 1 <= n) {
                if (unsortedList.get(c + 1).compareTo(unsortedList.get(c)) > 0) {
                    c += 1;
                }
            }
            if (unsortedList.get(i).compareTo(unsortedList.get(c)) >= 0) {
                break;
            }
            unsortedList = swap(unsortedList, i, c);
            i = c;
        }
        return unsortedList;
    }

    private static <T> List<T> swap(List<T> list, int firstIndex, int secondIndex) {
        assert list != null;
        assert list.size() > 0;
        assert 0 <= firstIndex;
        assert firstIndex < list.size();
        assert 0 <= secondIndex;
        assert secondIndex < list.size();
        if (firstIndex == secondIndex) {
            return list;
        }
        T tmpT = list.get(secondIndex);
        list.set(secondIndex, list.get(firstIndex));
        list.set(firstIndex, tmpT);
        return list;
    }
}
```

Should I assert on list size in softDown and siftUp? Is the passing back and forth of list references ok?

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i = n;;) {
    if (i == 0) {
        break;
    }
```

This look very odd instead you can do

```
for(int i = n; i > 0;){
```

Asserts are kinda useless in java, they only work when the jvm is started with the -ea flag (or you do some reflection). instead just test and throw the IllegalArgumentException in the public method and remove the obvious assertions that would throw anyway.

Comment: For private methods I most often rely on asserts actually; builds should always have the enable flag turned on. I keep other runtime exceptions for exposed methods. That's said, let me rephrase my question to: does it makes sense to wrap runtime exceptions with assert exceptions in this case, just to make it evident/readable it is an input validation?

Comment: The accepted pattern for input validation is an `if(check)throw` at the top of the method